# Exporting functions of Reactjs, undefined function error [Reactjs + Material UI]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm making an adaptive menu with Reactjs and Material UI, I've finished all, but when I'm trying to import
a defined a const in different file, unfortunately functions is not working.

The definition of function:

```
export const Adapting = ({
     openDrawer,
     setOpenDrawer,
}) => {
     const iOS = process.browser && /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent);
     const classes = useStyles();
     return(
         <React.Fragment>
             <SwipeableDrawer 
                 disableDiscovery = {iOS}
                 disableBackdropTransition = {!iOS}

                 open = {openDrawer}
                 onOpen  = {() => setOpenDrawer(true)}
                 onClose = {() => setOpenDrawer(false)}

                 className = {classes.__adaptivemenu__}
             >
                 <h2>Example Of Adaptation</h2>
             </SwipeableDrawer>
             <IconButton
                 disableRipple
                 onClick = {() => setOpenDrawer(!openDrawer)}
             >
                 <MenuIcon />
             </IconButton>
         </React.Fragment>
     );  
}
```

Importing component

```
import {Adapting} from './Adaptives';
```

Here is the part of code where I'm declaring function, in main file

```
const [openDrawer, setOpenDrawer] = useState(false);
```

Declaration of elements:

```
     {match ? 
         <Adapting
             open    = {openDrawer}
             onClick = {!openDrawer}
             onClose = {setOpenDrawer}
             onOpen  = {setOpenDrawer}
         /> 
     : qtabs}
```

Error is:

```
TypeError: setOpenDrawer is not a function
```

Comment: Can you show us what the exact error message is? Also, how are you importing `Adapting`?

Comment: `TypeError: setOpenDrawer is not a function` this is the error, and importing is `import {Adapting}from  './Adaptives';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to use a bit of typescript to explain this.

The props that you are expecting look like this:

```js
interface Props {
  openDrawer: boolean; // I'm not sure about this one
  setOpenDrawer(open: boolean): void;
}
```

What you are actually giving it:

```js
interface Props {
  open: boolean; // Again I'm not sure about this
  onClose(): void;
  onOpen(): void;
}
```

So you would have to change the usage of the component to:

```js
<Adapting>
  openDrawer={openDrawer}
  setDrawerOpen={setDrawerOpen}
/>
```

I would consider looking at your other props as well, you haven't posted your whole code (so I cannot tell), but they might be incorrect as well.

Comment: It worked, thank you very much `<Adapting>
  openDrawer={openDrawer}
  setDrawerOpen={setDrawerOpen}
/>` This is the solution

Comment: Glad to help @Sabretooth I would appreciate if you accepted the answer =)